# SSIS - Full RecordSet Use for Data Flow not possible

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Two tasks in an SSIS package, execute sql task ( Task 1 ) followed by a data flow task ( Task 2).

The execute sql task is a select code from Table 1 in Database 1. The full result set in stored in an object user variable called code.

In the Data flow I have a ADO.net Data source to a flat file. In the ADO.net source I have a query that hits a Database 2 , which is select product_records from Table 2 where code in ( @User:Code ) -- These codes come from Task 1.

So the big point is I do not want to go through record by record from the full result set . Is there a way I can use the object data type user variable code to achieve. I have tried a few ways and cant get it to work . So help ? This is SSIS 2008.

Comment: You could load the resultset into a table in Database2 and then JOIN the two tables in your DataSource query.   I know that there is a way to do it using the user variable with a Script transformation, but I don't remember how off the top of my head.

Comment: How large are the data sets t1 and t2? Does t2 only accept the ADO.NET provider or could you change it to use an OLE DB connection manager?

Comment: Unfortunately database 2 is not mine and not an option. I am open to any idea using variables, expressions, scripts etc . I need to get this done by the end of the week so fairly stressed over this seemingly simple blocker that has come up.

Comment: t1 is currently about 80 codes. t2 is a massive table with 1 million plus records. t2 only accepts ADO.net as is on an old database technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a script task between the two tasks. In there you can walk through all codes from task 1 and create a sql code that you store in a variable. You can refer to this variable at the ADO.Net source in your data flow task.

To loop through the records using a scripting task, you can look this blog [ssis-reading-object-variable-in-script-task](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11133/ssis-reading-object-variable-in-script-task.aspx)